# PHP If Statement (regarding numerical values)

Tags: php, if-statement

```
$a = 3;  
$b = $a++;

if ($a > $b) { echo “a > $b” }
else if ($a == $b) { echo “a = $b” }
else { echo “a < $b” }
```

When I work through this question, I get a=3, b=4 (3+1). Hence both the If and Else If conditions are false, so I go to Else and final answer is: a < 4.

However, the answer according to the mark scheme is: a > 3 meaning that the If condition is true. How could $a be larger than $b? Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the following statement:

```
$b = $a++;
```

The `++` is located **after** `$a`. This is the [post-increment](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php) operator.
It first returns the current value of `$a` (3), and only then increments `$a`. In other words, `$b` is assigned with `$a`'s current value, and then `$a` is incremented. So, `$a` is 4 and `$b` is 3, hence `$a > $b`.

Comment: Nicely explained. Cheers